# Convert a left-to-right plot to bottom-to-top (transpose not working)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a simple problem that I cannot quite understand why it doesn't work.

MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
test = np.random.rand(100,5)
plt.plot(test)
plt.show()
```

Produces

[image]

Now all I want to do is to quite literally transpose the whole `test` matrix so that my data on the x-axis is now plotted vertically instead (so `[0-100]` is on y instead). But when I do that:

```
plt.plot(test.T)
plt.show()
```

I get this instead

[image]

The data streams are thus being superimposed on top of each other rather than transposing the array. I was expecting the whole thing to just get flipped as so `x --> y` and `y --> x`. Perhaps what I want is not transpose. So the data is plotted horizontally now, and I just want to plot i vertically instead.

Hence, where am I going wrong? I have clearly misunderstood something very basic.

Answer (score 2):

Well this solved it...

```
plt.plot(test,range(100))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Generalising Astrid's answer, one can define a helper function to transpose the axis for any 1d-array plot, like this:

```
def transpose_plot(array):
    return plt.plot(array, range(len(array)))
```

---

**Demo:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def transpose_plot(array):
    return plt.plot(array, range(len(array)))

test = np.random.rand(100,5)
transpose_plot(test)
plt.show()
```

[image]